# volatile + object combination disallowed in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, volatile

I'm using an embedded compiler for the TI TMS320F28335, so I'm not sure if this is a general C++ problem (don't have a C++ compiler running on hand) or just my compiler. Putting the following code snippet in my code gives me a compile error:

```
"build\main.cpp", line 61: error #317: the object has cv-qualifiers that are not
compatible with the member function
        object type is: volatile Foo::Bar
```

The error goes away when I comment out the `initWontWork()` function below. What is the error telling me and how can I get around it without having to resort to using `static` functions that operate on a `volatile struct`?

```
struct Foo
{
    struct Bar
    {
        int x;
        void reset() { x = 0; }
        static void doReset(volatile Bar& bar) { bar.x = 0; } 
    } bar;
    volatile Bar& getBar() { return bar; }
    //void initWontWork() { getBar().reset(); }
    void init() { Bar::doReset(getBar()); } 
} foo;
```

Comment: cv-qualifiers means const _or_ volatile... That's a hint that you should know half of the answer already, just change the keyword. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the same way you cannot do this:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar();
};

const foo f;
f.bar(); // error, non-const function with const object
```

You cannot do this:

```
struct baz
{
    void qax();
};

volatile baz g;
g.qax(); // error, non-volatile function with volatile object
```

You must cv-qualify the functions:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar() const;
};

struct baz
{
    void qax() volatile;
};

const foo f;
f.bar(); // okay

volatile baz g;
g.qax(); // okay
```

So for you:

```
void reset() volatile { x = 0; }
```

Comment: Aha -- thanks! I've never seen the use of "volatile" in that manner.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted because it solved the problem. But, I think the answer would be better if you can explain *why* do we get the error: "In the same way you cannot do this: <- why?".